# Using sed to replace text with spaces with a defined variable with slashs

Tags: bash, unix, sed

I am trying to use sed to replace a line with spaces with a defined variable.

For example,

I want to replace 'a dumb string' with $lan, and lan="~/afile.py

I assumed the line would be

```
sed "s/a dumb string/$lan/g" file.txt
```

but this leave the 'a dumb string' part blank in the file.txt.

My problem seems simple enough. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure that you've set the variable `Ian`? What happens when you run `echo "<<$Ian>>"`?

Comment: Now is it a dump string or a dumb string?!

Comment: ha ha, it's a dumb string. Sorry, I'll correct the typo

Comment: @ruakh the $lan is set correctly, but I found the root of the problem. $lan is a file name and has slashes in it. I'll clarify the question.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I determined that because my @lan variable has slashes in it, I need to use the sed command using :

For example

```
sed "s:a dumb string:$lan:g" file.txt
```

This is probably a novice mistake, but I'm not that familiar with sed. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 18):

`sed` is not aware that you're passing a variable -- it'll be interpreted as just another part of your regex. If your substitution contains slashes, the easiest thing to do is use an alternate separator char, like this:

```
sed "s|a dumb string|$lan|g" file.txt
```

Answer (score 8):

Sometime space in search string does not work so needed to use [[:space:]] in centos.

```
    sed -i 's/User[[:space:]]daemon/User apache/' httpd1.conf
```

Comment: I would have cried for days if it wasn't for your answer here!