# Bash script replacing arbitrary input strings with arbitrary output strings containing spaces via sed

Tags: string, bash, sed, replace

I am new to Bash and am trying to create a bash function that can:

1) Find all file names matching that which is given (`$1`) recursively in my current directory's sub-folders

2) Locate and replace the whole line matching the pattern in a variable string (`$2`) with a second variable string (`$3`)

I think I am most of the way there, but am having trouble with replacing text strings containing spaces. My current function looks like:

```
rplcPhrase() {
    find . -name $1 -exec sed -i "/$2/c $3" {} + 
}

rplcPhrase $1 $2 $3
```

and command line input looks like

```
/link/to/file.sh "filetochange.txt" "\!phrase[[:space:]]to[[:space:]]change" "replacement[[:space:]]phrase"
```

Researching similar questions have explained the need to "escape" special characters (such as "!") in order to use in the pattern and that `[[:space:]]` must be used in the search pattern to account for spaces. However, I would like to return a phrase that contains a space. The result of the above command line input correctly finds the pattern

```
!phrase to change
```

but replaces it with

```
replacement[[:space:]]phrase
```

If I instead change `replacement[[:space:]]phrase` with `replacement phrase`, it only yields

```
replacement
```

Like I said, I feel like I'm almost there and am just missing something simple. Any help would be appreciated.

I've already searched for this and cannot find a solution that quite solves my problem. See links:
[Replace whole line containing a string using Sed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11245144/replace-whole-line-containing-a-string-using-sed)

[Using sed to replace text with spaces with a defined variable with slashs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15236237/using-sed-to-replace-text-with-spaces-with-a-defined-variable-with-slashs)

Comment: Quote your variables.

Comment: @Barmar where should I quote the variables? Within the sed command (`sed -i "/"$2"/c "$3""`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to quote the variables to prevent word splitting and wildcard expansion.

```
rplcPhrase() {
    find . -name "$1" -exec sed -i "/$2/c $3" {} + 
}

rplcPhrase "$1" "$2" "$3"
```

Comment: That fixed it. Thanks!